# Como usar un bucle if con un resultado de system.data.row

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo un servicio web que tiene como lógica un data set. Cuando uso LINQ para poder obtener un parámetro que deseo lo hago sin problemas.

Donde encuentro problemas es cuando llamo un segundo servicio web y tengo que hacer una condición `IF` para solamente obtener ciertos resultados basados en el estatus del proyecto.

¿De qué forma puedo integrar el resultado del data set con el filtro en el `IF` que tengo antes de proceder en mi ejecución?

Esto es lo que tengo en la llamada del servicio web del data set:

```
foreach (WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr.Distinct(new ProjectEqualityComparer()))
{
   string languages = "";
   string projectId = proj.ProjectID.ToString();
   //calling GetProjectDetails()
   var projectType = client.GetProjectDetails(ref apiKey, ref message, languages);
   var type = projectType.Tables["Table"].Select("ProjectId = '" + projectId    + "'").
              Where(s => s.Field<string>("DefinitionType") != "survey").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

La parte arriba del codigo me funciona bien, porque solamente me da los proyectos que no tengan la definicion de tipo "survey"

En la siguiente parte del código tengo mi condición `IF` donde necesito también filtrar los proyectos. Entonces lo que busco es que los proyectos no sean ni `expired`, `Not Published` y que no tengan como definición `survey`

Aquí está cómo llamo la condición:

```
if (proj.PublishStatus != "expired" && proj.PublishStatus != "Not Published")
```

Comment: Pero no usaste el AsEnumerable() para trabjar con el dataset ?  El Select() del linq recuerda que devuelve los campos que quieres trabajar, pero no aplica ningun filtro, es en el Where() donde filtras los datos. el if donde usas el PublishStatus != expired donde deberias aplicarlo ? sobre que objetos necesitas filtrar el PublishStatus

Comment: los filtros tienen que ser aplicados antes de entrar en el if porque dependiendo de ese filtro es donde podre llamar otro servicio web.

Comment: pero sobre que entidad aplicas el filtro ?

Comment: El filtro es usado en un principio por (WS.ProjectMetaData) y me resulta bien, pero necesito el definitionType y eso solo me lo puede dar llamando a este otro servicio web GetProjectDetails pero el viene de un data set, y es ahi donde no se como combinarlos

Comment: la verdad que no entiendo lo que planteas, una cosa es filtrar una primer coleccion y luego una distinta, si la priemr lista no tiene el dato del definitionType  no veo como podrias filtrar por este

Comment: ese era mi miedo de como poder hacerlo, he buscado bastante pero con esto me confirmas que no tengo como usar las 2 propiedades ya que se ven distintas

Comment: por lo que entiendo tienes dos listas de datos diferentes, una se obtiene a partir de la otra, pero las propiedades por las cuales quieres filtrar estan en cada una, salvo que de alguna forma puedas realizar algun join de los datos con linq y luego aplicar el filtro

Comment: exacto, necesito las propiedades de las 2 listas diferentes, una viene de un data set y la otra de una lista. Lo que no se es como poder juntarlas para crear ese filtro si esque se pudiera realizar

Comment: pero para obtener el dataset necesitas ejecutar N veces el metodo GetProjectDetails() o sea deberias ir acumulando las respuestas y al final unir todo en una unica entidad. Se podria ver de aplicar el Merge() del DataTable para ir acumulando las respuestas

Comment: Podrias indicarme como podria lograr lo que me indicas? gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Una pregunta tonta, te supone algún problema filtrar los proyectos en el propio foreach?

Answer (score 1):

Se podria ver de aplicar el Merge() del DataTable para ir acumulando las respuestas

[DataTable.Merge (Método)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DataTable dtMerged = null;

foreach (WS.ProjectMetaData proj in pr.Distinct(new ProjectEqualityComparer()))
{
    string languages = "";
    var projectType = client.GetProjectDetails(ref apiKey, ref message, languages);

    DataTable dt = projectType.Tables["Table"];

    if(dtMerged == null)
    {
        dtMerged = dt.Copy(); //o puedes usar el Clone()
    }

    dtMerged.Merge(dt);

}
```

al final del foreach tendras un unico datatable con los datos de todas las respuesta que devolvieron GetProjectDetails()

Sobre este aplicarias el linq para filtrar

Comment: Haciendo eso en el resultado aplicare el linq para filtrar pero caigo en lo mismo de como aplicar ese resultado del filtro a mi otro filtro que viene desde ProjectMetaData donde lo uso con el if

Comment: pero el primer filtro ya lo aplicas cuando limitas los datos de la primer lista. Tiene un resultado que filtras, entonces para que necesitas volverlo a filtrar pero con los datos de la invocacion del segundo metodo?

Comment: si el primer resultado me da lo que busco, pero eso de alguna forma tengo que relacionarlo con el resultado de la segunda llamada del segundo metodo. Ya que necesito obtener todos los proyectos que no esten publicacos, que no esten expirados y que no tengan como definicion survye. Es por eso que el ultimo parametro solo me lo da el llamado de ese servicio que viene del data set